# Loop task for given time using Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading

I currently have a method i would like to loop for a given time. I have tried creating two threads like this

```
            Thread t = new Thread();
            t.start();
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(length);
                        t.interrupt();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread s = new Thread(r);
            s.start();

            while(!t.isInterrupted()){
                runCurrentPres(current);
            }
```

But I cant seem to break the loop, t is never interrupted for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `isInterrupted` method is really more of a `hasPendingInterruption` than `wasEverInterrupted`. The flag is automatically cleared when an `InterruptedException` is thrown in that thread (which can only happen at certain points, like when you call sleep), or if anyone calls `interrupted()` (which is different from `isInterrupted()`).

Read the [official Java tutorial on Interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) for more info.

Threads that have exited can not have pending interruptions.

However, this is not a good way to limit your main thread's run time. Checking the time in every iteration would achieve what you want:

```
long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + length;
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
    runCurrentPres(current);
}
```

Note that this only checks between each `runCurrentPres` call, so if that function takes a long time to execute, your loop will finish a little later than intended. This is, however, the same behavior that your original code would've had if it worked.

Comment: Also, I'm not reputable enough to comment or downvote yet, but I really want to underline that JeramyRR's solution is *terrible*. That thread would be eating 100% of one core's CPU time **forever**, because it is never stopped!

Answer (score 2):

So what about this?

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (time + length > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    runCurrentPres(current);
}
```

No need to use threads.

Answer (score 0):

Using your suggestions i went with

```
long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + length;
while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
    runCurrentPres(current);
}
```

as mentioned in comments, the runcurrent takes time to execute because of a for loop. therefor i changed the solution to check before each iteration of the for loop, it ended up like this, and works just as intended

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (time + length > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        files = updateFiles(current);
        for (File f : files) {
            if(time + length < System.currentTimeMillis()){
                break;
            }
```

And yes, the solution with the while(true) inside the thread used 70% cpu